# How to check if the JTable is exist in the JFrame or not?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

Hie Friends.

I am developing an java application Which contain JTable.

But my problem is my JTable need to be Refresh time by time.

### Requirements:

1. My table contains one JCheckbox and Several JTextFields. The text of
2. table is added from jTextFields. When user click on checkbox the
3. specific row must be removed.

### Problem:

If JTable is exist and user refresh it (I use check-box for refresh) JTable doesn't Let him/her to refresh the data in this case Whole table is going to disable state.

Please give me solution about this problem.

Comment: Save the Components to a List. Later remove it from the List and your Panel or Frame.

Comment: Refresh the model, not the component.  This will still require to have a reference to at least the model, but since you're adding/removing data from the table I assume you have some kind of reference